# Separated audio and ptt

Tags: computer-control

how important and why is the audio, ptt ev. CAT interface separation from PC? I saw solutions with separating transformers and PTT, but directly connected CAT. Does it make sense? And is there any potential separated USB cable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's wrap this up from the back:

> And is there any potential separated USB cable?

Yes. You can buy these as isolated USB interface. They make sense in applications where e.g. medical-grade isolation between user interface and device is necessary, or where the device controlled over USB is somewhere that might experience things like discharge from large motors etc.

A CAT (computer-aided tuning) interface, however, classically isn't even USB – it's typically a serial controller (a UART), connected either via RS-232  level signal or TTL signaling. The USB adapter typically just contains a USB-to-serial converter doing the desired signal levels.

It's much easier to electrically isolate RS-232 or TTL serial lines than USB. So do that, you can buy ready-made ICs and boards.

You don't *need* potential separation, however. Your transceiver's case is typically on the same level as your USB shielding or serial line signal ground. You might want to avoid noisy current loops – but you'd do that using filters/clamp-on ferrites, typically.

There's legitimate concern about coupling noise from switching electronics (e.g. computers) into transceivers – but it all boils down to shielding. And I'd expect your transceiver to shield and filter its inputs reasonably well – after all, what are you expecting when you accept a digital signal? It's going to come from a digital device.